# This program is a combination of stacks queue and linked list

Tags: linked-list, stack, queue

I do not know how to solve this question and I have a deadline for this assignment can you please help me solving it:

> The car names are saved in a linked list. The customer orders are saved in the queue. You should take order from the beginning of the queue and search for it in the linked list, then delete it and put the sold car in the stack to be able to retrieve the last sold car.
> The program must be written in C language

Comment: You should state what you understand and what you tried before asking help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't share your attempt (your code) in your post, here I am sharing the pseudocode for this problem. You should write your own code to solve your assignment.

```
ProcessOrder(LinkedList<CarDetails> ll, Queue<Order> Q, Stack<Order> S):
    while(!Q.empty()):
        Order currentOrder = Q.top()
        Q.pop()
        
        CarDetails cd = findAndDeleteFromLinkList(ll, currentOrder.car_name)
        S.push(CarDetails)
```

Now to write the code by your own, you can use the following resources:

1. [How to use the STL stack in C++](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-use-the-stl-stack-in-cpp)
2. [Stack Implementation in C](https://www.techiedelight.com/stack-implementation/)
3. [How to Use C++ STL Queue with an Example Program](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/01/cpp-stl-queue/)
4. [How To Implement Queue in C?](https://www.edureka.co/blog/queue-in-c/)
5. [C function to find and delete a node from a singly linked list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/496/c-function-to-find-and-delete-a-node-from-a-singly-linked-list)